# What exactly this rewrite condition does?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm facing a problem to understand this `mod_rewrite` expression. I'm using `local xampp environment` which has a directory named `root` in the `htdocs` directory. When I enter in address bar like this `localhost/root` it opens up the `index.php` page. This is the code of `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /root/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I'm facing a problem on `line no 3`, I know `RewriteRule` will only work when condition becomes true. But what is the purpose of this condition. What it does in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this rule is to NOT match on any static files (defined as ending on .css, .js, .png, .jpg, .gif or robots.txt, case insensitive). Any request matching the rule (i.e. not ending on any of the specified strings) will get passed to index.php.

For example: if a request is for `/images/logo.png`, it ends with `.png` which means it DOES satisfy the condition between the parentheses, and therefore DOES NOT satisfy the entire expression. So, it will not get passed to `index.php`.
However, a request for `/blog/hello-world/` DOES NOT end with one of the mentioned strings, therefore it DOES satisfy the entire expression. Hence it will get handled by `index.php`.

Comment: Can you please explain with this some simple example

Comment: I hope this explanation helps :)